# Server not returning a response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an ajax call that inserts into my database, the call goes out and the database is updated but I do not get any response back from the server. 
I have confirm it using firebug as there is a post tab but no response tab as usual.

I have posted my code below, any help would be amazing.

```
function addCourse()
    {

    var memid = document.forms["addCoursesForm"]["Member"].value;
    var CourseName = document.forms["addCoursesForm"]["CourseNames"].value;
    var CourseDate = document.forms["addCoursesForm"]["Cdate"].value;
    var CourseExpiry = document.forms["addCoursesForm"]["Edate"].value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readystate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("ConfirmCourse").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "addCourseDB.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("memid="+ memid+ "&CourseName="+ CourseName+ "&CourseDate=" + CourseDate+"&CourseExpiry="+ CourseExpiry);
```

Comment: I do not know why you have a jquery-ajax tag.  You should show your server side code.

Comment: The server side is inserting into the database and echos an 'Inserted!' back to the user

Answer (score 0):

I would change this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "addCourseDB.php");
```

to:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "addCourseDB.php",true);
```

this way the onreadystatechange will be properly handled for the event (as an async event).

OR, better yet, start using jQuery so you do not have to do all this heavy lifting of the xmlhttp stuff yourself.

EDIT: here is a definative reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding true but it still doesnt work. Its like the if (xmlhttp.readystate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) is not firing. The DB is getting updated and the 'Record Inserted' is being returned in firebug but not sent to the user.